# How to find the integral that generates $X$ number in Maple 17?

Tags: calculus, integration, maple

By a challenge of my calculus' professor, we have to find a integral that generates a $8$ digit number, such as $12345678$.
Since there is an infinite number of integrals that could result in a $8$ digit number, is there a way to do it in Maple, in order to list some of the integrals that could do it?

Comment: use literally any known definite integral at all and scale properly by multiplying through the terms?

Comment: @RobBland: I think that is an answer, not a comment. Maybe add an example like $12345678\int_0^1 dx$

Comment: $\int_0^{100}x^3\,dx$

Comment: $\frac19\int_1^{10}(x^8-1)dx$

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment by Rob Bland, you can use any known integral.

My integral of choice would be $$\int_0^{12345678} 1dx=12345678$$

Answer (score 0):

To close this out: an example of an integral that produces the number $N$ is 
$$
\int_0^1 N ~ dx = \left. Nx \right|_0^1 = N\cdot1 - N \cdot 0 = N.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$11! = \int_0^\infty x^{11}e^{-x}\ dx$.

Anyway, since as you say there are infinitely many, come up with your own!